# Не добавляется элемент в список python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Вот текст задачи:

> Вы парсите логи сервера. Напишите программу, которая будет считать количество запросов к серверу, сгруппированных по статус кодам, а так же ниже количество запросов, сгруппированных по адресу. Отсортируйте результат по возрастанию.
> Ввод заканчивается ключевым словом end

````
```

Sample Input:

/api/admin 200
/api/admin 400
/cities 200
/users/create 201
/users/1/delete 204
/users/2/delete 204
/users/2/delete 404
end
Sample Output:

200 2
201 1
204 2
400 1
404 1
/api/admin 2
/cities 1
/users/1/delete 1
/users/2/delete 2
/users/create 1

```
````

Я понимаю как решить задачу, но у меня не получается собрать два списка с данными, они получаются пустыми, что я делаю не так?
Вот мой код:

````
```

ch, i = [], None
sl = []
while i != 'end':
    i = input()
    if i == 'end':
        exit()
    i = i.split(' ')
    #i[0]=/addadada/adawdad i[1]=202
    sl.append(i[0])
    ch.append(int(i[1]))
print(sl)
print(ch)

```
````

Comment: `exit()` вам зачем? почему не `break`?

Comment: я как начал обучаться, стал тестировать код частями и по привычке поставил `exit()`, так как в прошлых программах именно он и нужен был

Comment: @iNew я заменил в вашем коде `exit` на `break` и у меня вывелись два списка

Comment: вместо списков лучше использовать словари, поскольку нужно группировать данные

Comment: спасибо, действительно виноват был `exit()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как уже сказали в комментариях ваша проблема была в том, что вместо `break` у вас стоял `exit()`.

Дополнительно хочу показать, как эту задачу можно решить более оптимальным способом.

Лучше всего использовать словарь, поскольку вам нужно хранить именно соответствие кода запроса и их количества.

Типовая задача на подсчет количества элементов с использованием словаря решается следующим образом:

```
requests = {}

inp = input()

while inp != 'end':
    request, code = inp.split()
    if code in requests:
        requests[code] += 1
    else:
        requests[code] = 1
    inp = input()

requests = dict(sorted(requests.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))

print(requests)
```

Это не полное решение вашей задачи, а лишь типовой алгоритм того, как лучше реализовывать подобные вещи.